# Encryption for Sharepoint 2010 / 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server

I'm looking for File encryption on file shares where multiple users have to access a file.

My first approach was EFS but that not good solution for file shares only for local encryption.

Another option would be to use software from Symantec, but actually I don't want another system that i have to administrate.

Since we are using SharePoint 2010 and hopefully as soon as possible 2013, I thought I might be able to use SharePoint as a secure data storage.
I know I can setup Client Certificate Authentication via ADFS for SharePoint so I would have a secure access.

The other Part would be to secure my data. Is there any encryption for files in SharePoint so that someone cannot steal my data and open it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to encrypt your SharePoint data, and generally quite easy to do.

By default, SharePoint stores files and documents as "blobs" in a SQL Server database. SQL Server (from at least SQL Server 2008 onwards, maybe earlier) supports "Encryption at rest" using "Transparent data encryption". There's a good article on how to configure this on [Technet here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rycampbe/archive/2013/10/14/securing-sharepoint-harden-sql-server-in-sharepoint-environments.aspx)

In some cases, SharePoint is configured to use "Remote Blob Storage", which means that SQL Server stores files as regular files on file system. Unfortunately encryption is not supported with remote blob storage.